# Expected Value and Variance - Finding expected winnings

Tags: probability, statistics

A game is played where a fair coin is tossed until the first tail occurs.

The probability $x$ tosses will be needed is:

$$f(x)=(0.5)^x;x=1,2,3,\ldots$$

You win $2^x$ dollars if $x$ tosses are needed for $x=1,2,3,4,5$  but lose $256$ dollars if $x>5$

Determine your expected winnings

I'm a little confused on where to start in this question, if anyone can lead me in the right direction that'll be great, thanks!!

Comment: What happens if $x= 5$?

Comment: Sorry, edited!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \left(\sum_{x=1}^5 2^x\cdot\Pr(\text{winnings}= x)\right) - 256\cdot\Pr(\text{winnings}=256) \\[8pt]
= {} &  \left(\sum_{x=1}^5 2^x\cdot(0.5)^x\right) - 256\cdot \Pr\Big(\text{heads on all five of the first five tosses}\Big) 
\end{align}

Now simplify the expression $2^x (0.5)^x$ and figure out the probability of getting heads on all five of the first five tosses.

Comment: Sorry in your expression it says "heads on all five of first five tosses", but you said to find getting heads on all four of first five tosses? So im guessing its the expression that is correct right?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be minus 256 instead of adding, because we are going to lose 256 instead?

Comment: I missed the part about losing $256$.  As for "four" instead of "five", I wrote some of this before the question got edited.

Comment: Sorry about that, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the random variable indicating # of the toss in which the first tail occurred. Let $Y$ be a random variable which indicates the amount of money you earned.

We are given that $X$ has a probability function $P_X(x) =\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^x=\mathbb P(X=x)$.

It is clear that $Y$ takes the values $2,4,8,16,32,-256$.

By definition: 
$$\mathbb E(Y) = \sum\limits_{y}y\;\mathbb P(Y=y) = \left[\sum\limits_{y}y\;\mathbb P(2^X=y)\right]-256\;\mathbb P(2^X=y)$$$$=\left[\sum\limits_{y}y\;\mathbb P(X\ln2=\ln |y|)\right]-256\;\mathbb P(X\ln2=\ln 256)$$
$$=\left[\sum\limits_{y}y\;\mathbb P\left( X=\frac{\ln |y|}{\ln2}\right)\right]-256\;\mathbb P\left( X=\frac{\ln 256}{\ln2}\right)$$
$$=\left[\sum\limits_{y}y(0.5)^{\frac{\ln |y|}{\ln2}}\right]-256(0.5)^{\frac{\ln 256}{\ln2}}$$
$$=\left[\sum\limits_{y}y(0.5)^{\frac{\ln |y|}{\ln2}}\right]-1.$$

Now compute $\mathbb E(Y^2)$ and apply $\mathbb{Var}(Y) = \mathbb E(Y^2)-(\mathbb E(Y))^2$.